Apply active class to React side nav using IntersectionObserver. Intersection is not capturing correctly
Issue: Works fine while scrolling bottom to top, but not otherwise
Problem:
I am using smooth scrolling for navigation in my app, and everything works perfectly when scrolling from bottom to top. However, when I try to scroll from top to bottom, the scroll does not behave as expected.
Here is the relevant code where I am implementing smooth scrolling and handling active section highlights:

const NavItem = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 12px;
    padding: 12px;
    gap: 8px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: var(--grey-80);
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 14px;

    ${(props) =>
        props.active &&
        css`
            background-color: var(--primary-light);
            color: var(--grey-100);
            font-weight: 700;

            ${NavIcon} {
                background-color: var(--primary-color);
                color: var(--white);
                font-weight: 700;
                border: 1px solid var(--primary-color);
            }
        `}
`;

const Navbar = ({ activeSectionId }) => {
    const smoothScrollTo = (targetId) => {
        const target = document.getElementById(targetId);

        if (target) {
            target.scrollIntoView({
                block: "start",
                behavior: "smooth",
            });
        }
    };

    return (
        <NavContainer>
            {ODMNavConfig.map((item, index) => {
                const isActive = activeSectionId === item.itemId;

                return (
                    <NavItem
                        key={item.itemId}
                        active={isActive}
                        onClick={() => smoothScrollTo(item.itemId)}
                    >
                        <NavIcon>{index + 1}</NavIcon>
                        <>{item.title}</>
                    </NavItem>
                );
            })}
        </NavContainer>
    );
};

export default Navbar;

const sections = useRef([]);

const location = useLocation();
const { moodboardId, lineID } = location.state || {};

useEffect(() => {
    const observerCallback = (entries) => {
        entries.forEach((entry) => {
            if (entry.isIntersecting) {
                setActiveSectionId(entry.target.id);
            }
        });
    };

    const observer = new IntersectionObserver(observerCallback, {
        root: null,
        threshold: 0.5,
    });

    sections.current.forEach((section) => observer.observe(section));

    return () => {
        sections.current.forEach((section) => observer.unobserve(section));
    };
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
    if (activeSection) {
        history.push(`${activeSection}`);
    }
}, [activeSection]);

<FlexRow
    gap={24}
    alignItems="flex-start"
    style={{
        paddingLeft: "5%",
        paddingRight: "5%",
    }}
>
    <Navbar activeSectionId={activeSectionId} />
    <FormContainer>
        <WBox id="brick-description" ref={(el) => (sections.current[0] = el)}>
            <BrickDescription
                loading={loading}
                setSelectedBrickData={setSelectedBrickData}
                setArticleCode={setArticleCode}
                designData={designData[0]}
            />
        </WBox>
        <WBox id="design-and-colorway" ref={(el) => (sections.current[1] = el)}>
            <DesignAndColor
                selectedBrickData={selectedBrickData}
                brickColorways={brickColorways}
                moodboardId={moodboardId}
                designId={designData[0]?.designId}
                odmDesignData={designData}
                setColorwayData={setColorwayData}
            />
        </WBox>
        <WBox id="costing" ref={(el) => (sections.current[2] = el)}>
            <FabricCosting
                selectedBrickData={selectedBrickData}
                setOdmDesignData={setOdmDesignData}
                moodboardId={moodboardId}
                lineId={lineID}
                setBrickColorways={setBrickColorways}
                setDisableBtn={setDisableBtn}
                designID={designData[0]?.designId}
                articleCode={articleCode}
            />
        </WBox>
        <WBox id="comments" ref={(el) => (sections.current[3] = el)}>
            <VendorComments
                moodboardId={moodboardId}
                designID={designData[0]?.designId}
            />
        </WBox>
    </FormContainer>
</FlexRow>

